# Issues reading PySpark dataframe into Pandas with VectorUDT columns

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have a PySpark table where many columns are type VectorUDT. These columns have been created using the OneHotEstimator function in PySpark.

I can write this table to Parquet files, but when I try to read the table back in to Pandas using PyArrow, I get this exception:

```
ArrowNotImplementedError: Currently only nesting with Lists is supported.
```

Is there any way to get around this? I would prefer not having to break up each VectorUDT column into their individual columns.

Answer (score 0):

The output columns of the OneHotEncoderModel.transform() method are encoded as SparseVector.  You would have to manually create the individual vectors in order to bring them back into Pandas.  Send the original columns (the inputs to the Spark encoder) to Pandas, and re-encode them there if they are needed.

Spark estimators (such as Logistic Regression) will require the Sparse Vector encoded version, and you really don't want to expand these on the Spark side if your data are big.  Perhaps what you need to do on the Pandas side is small enough to make expanding them bearable?